# how to run this script with any number of digit value in bracket

Tags: javascript

i am trying to run this script to take any length of value and calculate greater and less

I try to run this script and it works with 2 testing parameter correctly but with 3rd testing parameter it does not work correctly

```
<script>
var batchNo = '25-Dec-2018 - t58 ( 341 )0';
//var batchNo='01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 0 )0';
//var batchNo='02-May-2019 - 0012345 ( 53 )0';
//var qty='0';
var qty = '35';
//var qty='55';
//var qty='390';
var startpos = batchNo.indexOf("( ");
var endpos = batchNo.indexOf(" )");
var stockQty = batchNo.substring(startpos + 2, endpos);
if (qty > stockQty) {
    alert("Entered quantity can not be greater than stock quantity, please try again.");
    //return false;
}
if (qty <= stockQty) {
    alert("Entered quantity ok");
    //return true;
}
</script>
```

check all qty value with all batchNo.

error when `qty=35 and batchNo = '25-Dec-2018 - t58 ( 341 )0'`

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're comparing with the `qty > stockQty` and such. You're not converting those to numbers and you're also not using length on the string so what is being compared?

Comment: add `stockQty = Number(stockQty)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should  convert qty and stockQty to number like this :

```js
var batchNo = '25-Dec-2018 - t58 ( 341 )0';
//var batchNo='01-Dec-2018 - t57 ( 0 )0';
//var batchNo='02-May-2019 - 0012345 ( 53 )0';
//var qty='0';
var qty = 35;
//var qty='55';
//var qty='390';
var startpos = batchNo.indexOf("( ");
var endpos = batchNo.indexOf(" )");
var stockQty = +batchNo.substring(startpos + 2, endpos);
if (qty > stockQty) {
    alert("Entered quantity can not be greater than stock quantity, please try again.");
    //return false;
}
if (qty <= stockQty) {
    alert("Entered quantity ok");
    //return true;
}
```

Comment: I agree that you can use the unary operator but from what I've seen most people don't know you can do that and it's more clear and intuitive to just `parseFloat` or `Number` personally

Answer (score 1):

you need to convert the string into numbers to compare them or else it you're just is this string less than that string and so on. give this a try

```
var qty=35; // turn you're quantities into actual numbers not string
//var qty='55';
//var qty='390';
var startpos = batchNo.indexOf("( ");
var endpos = batchNo.indexOf(" )");
var stockQty = parseInt(batchNo.substring(startpos + 2, endpos)); // convert you're stockQty string into a number
```